# Icon is not displaying in android studio APK file

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

hey there I have created an android application and I have set an icon to it in the Image asset and it worked well. When I run the emulator it displays the icon but the problem is that when I build an APK file of it and I transfer it to my mobile and run it it is not displaying the icon instead the same android logo is displaying.
Thanks if anyone can help me to sort out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing `android:roundIcon` and `android:icon` in your manifest file?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"

    /*Change these*/
    android:icon="@drawable/yourIcon"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/yourIcon"
    

    android:label="GPS Test"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```